# Getting input from text area and echoing it out

Tags: php, html

I have written some basic code so that a text area is displayed, and when the user inputs the text, clicks submit and it shows on the page in the method=''.

The code i have for the form is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Fun Translator</h1>

<form method="post" action="query.php">
 <textarea name="txtarea">
 </textarea>
 <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The code on the page query.php is:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
echo $_POST["txtarea"];
?>


</body>
</html>
```

By looking at google, other questions and such, this should work, but doesnt!

Solution:

Thanks to Marc Audet, I put in phpinfo and all that came up in a big table as it does, I took it out and it started working. Any explanations?

Comment: Try adding a "name" to the input field <input type="submit" name="send" value="whatever" />

Comment: BTW, you should filter the query for "unwanted" code to prevent SQL injections and such... example: `$yourquery=strip_tags(trim($_POST["txtarea"]));`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, in the query.php page, add `<pre><?php print_r($_POST); ?></pre>` and see what POST is giving you.

Comment: @Damien Pirsy - thanks but didnt work. @jackjoe - cool, good idea

Comment: try a GET instead of a POST, maybe the POST is not supported at your server?

Comment: @Marc Audet - as soon as I put that in a big table come up with lots of information. And then I took the php_info thing out and refreshed and now it works?  Wierd huh

Comment: Perhaps, you have a sticky browser cache, IE can really hang onto a page.  If you are running on a local machine, your browser could be misreading a time stamp.  These things happen can happen. 

Clearing the cache is one sure way of flushing out old pages and starting fresh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this code is perfectly fine. something else is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The textarea is not link to your form, you should add form="" in textarea like this:

```
<form method="post" action="query.php" name="myform">
<textarea name="txtarea" form="myform">
```

Answer (score 1):

use 
`echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);` 
to get value.

Comment: This is a security feature. He is asking how to get the value, not how to process it.

Answer (score 0):

some browsers like the ID...

add an ID like this:

```
<form method="post" action="query.php">
 <textarea name="txtarea" id="txtarea">
 </textarea>
 <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: The `id` of an `<input>` (or `<select>` or `<textarea>`) element is never passed to the `action` of a `<form>` on submit.  It is only accessible from the `document` object (in JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

Best guess: Your server doesn't support PHP.

Check the source code as delivered to the browser. If the `<?php` bit shows up, then the server hasn't run the page through a PHP engine.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you should be doing textarea in the quotes not txtarea, I am not really sure though, it might be beneficial to use an ID instead.